# Testing image on MNIST model , Python TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I recently started learning python and tensorflow simultaneously , I am currently working on MNIST, here is the code, model training and testing on MNIST data set is done , my next task is to take an image from computer, import it in my program and test that image on my trained model .So I have 2 questions

1. How can I save my model so that I dont have to run it again and again ?
2. How image can be imported and tested on this model so that the model can predict which number is this

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf`
   from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

   mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
   n_nodes_hl1 = 500
   n_nodes_hl2 = 500
   n_nodes_hl3 = 500
   n_classes = 10
   batch_size = 100
   x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
   y = tf.placeholder('float')

   def neural_network_model(data):
       hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                         'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
   hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                     'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

   hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                     'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

   output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                   'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])), }

   l1 = tf.add(
       tf.matmul(
           data,
           hidden_1_layer['weights']),
       hidden_1_layer['biases'])
   l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

   l2 = tf.add(
       tf.matmul(
           l1,
           hidden_2_layer['weights']),
       hidden_2_layer['biases'])
   l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

   l3 = tf.add(
       tf.matmul(
           l2,
           hidden_3_layer['weights']),
       hidden_3_layer['biases'])
   l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

   output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

   return output


   def train_neural_network(x):
       prediction = neural_network_model(x)
       cost = tf.reduce_mean(
           tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
               logits=prediction, labels=y))
       optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
   hm_epochs = 10
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

       for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
           epoch_loss = 0
           for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
               epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
               _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={
                               x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
               epoch_loss += c

           print(
               'Epoch',
               epoch,
               'completed out of',
               hm_epochs,
               'loss:',
               epoch_loss)

       correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

       accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
       print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval(
           {x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))

   train_neural_network(x)
   ```

Comment: I have found the solution for "saving and reusing the model"

Comment: Your iamge data ends up as an array of numbers representing the image anyway. So you could always create a new inference script that loads the model and then will just evaluate an image. No need to create big dataset reading functions for just one image.

Answer (score 0):

Your model has an output tensor `prediction`. If you feed only image it should contain 10 numbers. The index of the highest number is the prediction (you are already using tf.argmax(prediction, 1) to do this).

To get just the prediction, you can do

```
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: <numpy array or tensor containing the 784 floats representing your image>})`
```

Comment: i have converted the image to 784 sized float array and it is now predicting that particular image, but the predictions are mostly wrong , how can i normalize my images so that prediction is accurate ?

Comment: model accuracy is 92% and it predicts test data set accurately , the only problem occurs when i use my own image for prediction, predictions are mostly wrong

Comment: This is a generic ML question, and not quite suitable for StackOverflow (https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is the more appropriate forum), but some possible things to look at. Is your image very different from the training set? Is the conversion "accurate"? You can look at the tutorials in here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist. It has a few models from simple to more complex models.